# Prevent accidental deleting or updating tasks through API

Tags: asana

I am trying to use the Asana API. One things that concerns me is that you can create, delete and update tickets on there. Is it possible to restrict the API to be read-only?

Answer (score 0):

Your Asana API token is linked to the account you requested it under. As such whatever access that account has to projects and its ability to interact with them will also be available to the token.

You could create a second user account and set restrictions for each project it has access to be comment only. Which will not allow that user to create, delete, or update any of the tasks within those projects.